# Widgets sliding from outside the screen in Flutter ? Similar to Android 8 app drawer

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am writing a flashcard app (an extension to the open source AnkiDroid app) in Flutter. The basic workflow is: the app shows me a question and I can reveal the answer. The gesture I want in order to reveal the answer is similar to the Android 8 swipe up from the bottom icon row to reveal the app drawer. A fast swipe (or fling in the android terminology?) can reveal the app list, but a drawn out, slow swipe can control the motion of the apps drawer.

My questions are the following:

- What is the proper way to have widgets slide in from outside the screen ? Flutter complains that I'm trying to display widgets outside the screen, suggests I use ClipRect, but I haven't found a way for ClipRect to only display something the size of the screen (it seems to adjust itself to the size of the child)
- What is the recommended layout for what I want to do ? Currently I have the question and answer in a Column, and in order to center the question initially and hide the question, I modify the padding. It feels like a bit of a hack.
- Is there a helper library that can help me achieve the exact swipe/fling motion that I'm after? It needs to take into account momentum and position in order for the motion to feel just as natural as the android 8 app drawer.

Thank you for any suggestions you may have.

Here are the screens I have so far:

**Question screen**

[image: question screen]

**Answer screen (after swiping up)**

[image: answer screen]

And here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
// Uncomment lines 7 and 10 to view the visual layout at runtime.
//import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart' show debugPaintSizeEnabled;

void main() {
  //debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(MyApp());
}

/*
 * travel around the world
 * 環遊世界
 * wàan jàu sâi gâai
 */

class Card extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => CardState();
}

class CardState extends State<Card> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  var _dragStartOffset;

  Animation<double> questionAnimation;
  Animation<double> answerAnimation;
  Animation<double> opacityAnimation;
  AnimationController controller;

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250), vsync: this);
    questionAnimation = Tween(begin: 250.0, end: 150.0).animate(controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          // the state that has changed here is the animation object’s value
        });
      });
    answerAnimation = Tween(begin: 200.0, end: 32.0).animate(controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          // the state that has changed here is the animation object’s value
        });
      });
    opacityAnimation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          // the state that has changed here is the animation object’s value
        });
      });

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget question = Container(
        padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top: questionAnimation.value),
        child: Center (
            child: Text(
              "travel around the world",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 48.0,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            )
        ),
    );

    Widget answer = Container(
        padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top: answerAnimation.value),
        child: Opacity(
          opacity: opacityAnimation.value,
          child: Text(
              "wàan jàu sâi gâai 環遊世界",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 48.0,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            )
        )
    );

    var children = [question, answer];

    var child = GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
            controller.reset();
        },
        onVerticalDragUpdate: (data) {
          // print(data);
          var currentOffset = data.globalPosition;
          var travel = _dragStartOffset - currentOffset;
          // print(travel);

          if(travel.dy <0 )
          {
            return;
          }

          // cannot be lower than zero
          var travelY = max<double>(0.0, travel.dy);
          // cannot be higher than 100
          travelY = min<double>(200.0, travelY);

          var animationPosition = travelY / 200.0;
          controller.value = animationPosition;
        },
        onVerticalDragEnd: (data) {
          if(controller.value > 0.50) {
            // make the animation continue on its own
            controller.forward();
          } else {
            // go back the other way
            controller.reverse();
          }
        },
        onVerticalDragStart: (data) {
          //print(data);
          _dragStartOffset = data.globalPosition;
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('AnkiReview'),
          ),
          body:  Container(
              child:Column(
                children: children,
              )
          ),
        )

    );


    return child;



  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Card(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out one solution. It involves a **Column**, the top is just a **Container** with the question, but the bottom is a **PageView** which has a blank first page. The user can slide up to reveal the answer.

It solves the clipping issue, and also the physics issue, because PageView has built-in physics and snapping, which would otherwise not be trivial to build (I would probably have to use a CustomScrollView).

code:

```
// Copyright 2017 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
// Uncomment lines 7 and 10 to view the visual layout at runtime.
//import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart' show debugPaintSizeEnabled;

void main() {
  //debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(MyApp());
}

/*
 * travel around the world
 * 環遊世界
 * wàan jàu sâi gâai
 */

class Card extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => CardState();
}

class CardState extends State<Card> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  var _dragStartOffset;

  var _fontSize = 48.0;
  static const _padding = 28.0;

  initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var questionText = Text(
      "travel around the world",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: _fontSize,
      ),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    );

    var answerText = Text(
        "wàan jàu sâi gâai 環遊世界",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: _fontSize,
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center
    );


    Widget question = Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: _padding),
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: questionText
    );

    Widget answer = Container(
        padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top: _padding),
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: answerText

    );

    var card = Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: question,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: PageView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: [
              Container(),
              answer
            ]
          )
        )
      ]
    );

    return card;

  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('AnkiReview'),
        ),
        body:  Container(
            child:Card()
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```